# Shortening weekdays in user locale pt-PT with the use of the JS native Intl library

Tags: javascript, intl

We have a piece of code that returns a shortened weekday via the users' language preferences.

These preferences can be accessed in Javascript via `navigator.languages`.
We use these weekdays in a calendar. So we don't have too much horizontal space to show the text.

We use the Intl.DateTimeFormat to determine how we should shorten these weekdays.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat
MDN Also has a great piece of code which you can play around in. For our problem you can try entering:

```
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('nl-NL', { weekday: 'short' }).format(new Date(Date.UTC(2022, 12, 19, 3, 23, 16, 738))));
```

Up until now, everything is pretty default and working.
The problem comes in if a user has a locale of `pt-PT`.

For `pt`, and `pt-BR` the result for 2022-12-19 return: `qui.`
For `pt-PT` however, it just returns the full day: `quinta`

If I look at documentation about this (f.e. https://www.localeplanet.com/icu/pt-PT/index.html) this looks to be correct, and therefore it doesn't seem to be an implementation issue.

My question is how can I fix this without specifying

```
const realLocale = locale === 'pt-PT' ? 'pt' : locale;
```

And if this is a bug in the Intl library. Is there somewhere I can appeal or report this bug?

Comment: What fix would be warranted?

Comment: I would love to have a similar result as to pt or pt-BR. without having to manually specify that pt-Pt is an exception. The reason for this is that we cannot possibly build exceptions for every possible "mistake" that we find.

P.S: Argumentation / explanation as to why this is might also be helpful

Comment: A cleaner method than a ternary for each exception (or the like) would be a map of exceptional locales to their corresponding "working" locale. Then it would be used as follows: `const realLocale = localeMap[locale] ?? locale`. Of course, you would still have to find and add every single exception, so it would be a "lesser of the two evils" solution.

Comment: So, this also requires discerning if the format is actually "corrupt". Other formats as to `weekday: short` still work properly. And we do want to use pt-PT for those.